# Alterar cores no gráfico

Tags: r

Boa tarde. Como faço para atribuir cores diferentes para cada linha e como deixar vermelho a parte do gráfico acima da linha superior e abaixo da linha inferior?

```
a<-c(5.8, 9.8, 2.4, 4.4, 4.6, 5.6, 5.6, 7.4, 6.6, 7.6, 7.4, 9.2, 7.4, 4.0, 5.6)
matplot(cbind(a, 6, 6.2, 4, 8), type ='l')
```

Answer (score 5):

Para a primeira pergunta, você pode fornecer um vetor de cores para o argumento `col`. Neste exemplo vou deixar a linha principal preta e as outras em cinza:

```
cor = c('black', rep('gray', 4))
```

Para a segunda pergunta, uma opção é trabalhar com a função `clip()`. Ela define uma região do plot que será "plotável":

```
a <- c(5.8, 9.8, 2.4, 4.4, 4.6, 5.6, 5.6, 7.4, 6.6, 7.6, 7.4, 9.2, 7.4, 4.0, 5.6)
matplot(cbind(a, 6, 6.2, 4, 8), type ='l', col = cor)

# você poderá automatizar essa parte de definir as coordenadas
clip(0, 15, 0, 4)
lines(a, col = 2)
clip(0, 15, 8, 19)
lines(a, col = 2)
```